# What is the duty-free allowance limit when purchasing electronics in Hong Kong?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, airport-security, electronic-items, hong-kong

I am planning to travel from UK to Hong Kong and buy there some electronics (either iPhone, iPad or Mac mini‎).

Then I'm travel by air to Philippines, Singapore, Malaysia, Thailand and back to UK.

Therefore I've main question:

- What is the limit for buying duty-free electronics in Hong Kong?

And few related to interpret situation in the right way:

- Does it make any difference if the device (mobile or laptop) is unboxed, so I can say it's mine? Or they can check it's Hong Kong's laptop (based on the serial or something?).
- If I buy over limit, I can simply pay extra tax? How much?
- I'm traveling with my girlfriend, does the total splits into 2 people?
- Does the limit sum up with other shoppings such as small gifts, clothes, etc.?

I'm travelling only with hand luggage, own laptop and mobile (I could go without) and I've dual-citizenship (UK and EU) if that makes any difference.

Comment: I highly recommend you have a read of the [help]. Asking multiple questions in one is generally frowned upon, and likely to get closed as too broad.

Comment: @MarkMayo: It's one question, the other are help questions to interpret the main with the right way, because the limit that can change based on the situation (such as having the company, or traveling with someone). I've removed one extra question, which could go separately, other are dependent.

Comment: Your questions are not about *buying*, they are about importing the stuff you bought elsewhere afterwards.

Comment: Duties are applied when you take products into a new country, not when you purchase them.

Comment: @Flimzy: Thanks. But if I'm traveling to many countries, do I pay the duty in the next one, or in my original country?

Comment: You pay duty wherever you are importing them. Generally if you take items with you when you leave the country, it's not considered an import, but those rules can depend on the country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on buying duty free items, but there are limits on how much you can bring in duty free when you come home to the UK.  As far as Hong Kong is concerned you can buy as much as you please.

The limits on importing items into the UK will be per person, so you and your girlfriend each get an allotted amount and if you exceed that amount then duties are levied (you need to check with UK Customs on percentages).

The issue that you might encounter is taking those brand new electronics to the various countries you plan to visit.  If you plan to use them personally and unbox them, likely they will be passed through as personal possessions without worry.  But if you plan to take them home unopened (such as a gift for someone back home), then customs inspectors in the individual countries might want some proof that you are re-exporting them rather than selling them (especially since import taxes on new iPhones and such are quite high in SE Asian countries, there have been recent arrests in Thailand of people bringing in new iPhone6 which haven't been released in Thailand officially yet)